# Set font as per width

Tags: iphone, ios, uipickerview

Hello friends I am displaying text in UIPickerview row. But when the label size is too big then Picker row displays ... at the end of the label.

I want to display whole title in row of Picker instead of this. Can i set the font size automatically as per the title width in pickerview.

Comment: I did not clear ida about this,
but once go through this link,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5038891/center-uipickerview-text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement following method:

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view{

    UILabel* tView = (UILabel*)view;

    if (!tView){

        tView = [[UILabel alloc] init];

        // Setup label properties - frame, font, colors etc
        ...
    }

    // Fill the label text here
    ...
    return tView;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your controller a UIPickerViewDelegate and UIPickerViewDataSource, then you can use this routine to make any custom change you want for your picker row:

```
-(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view{

//make your own view here, it can be a UILabel if you want, or other kind of view.

//You can give it any size font you need.

}
```